# Xcode Error When Added AdMob Plugin To Ionic Project

Tags: xcode, ionic3, admob

I have an Ionic 3 Project and its running normally on Ionic DevApp And Xcode. But When i added AdMob Plugin , its running normally Ionic DevApp but its not running on Xcode. I tried Simulator and Real Device but i have some mistake both of them.

There is my error codes;

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception
'GADInvalidInitializationException', reason: 
'The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. 
Google AdMob publishers should follow instructions here: 

https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-ios-update-plist 
to include the AppMeasurement framework, 
set the -ObjC linker flag, and set 
GADApplicationIdentifier with a valid App ID. 

Google Ad Manager publishers should follow 
instructions here: 
https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-ios-update-plist
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Have had this problem for two days now. The problem seems that the xcode project's plist file is not getting the admob settings right. So had to add them manually like this:

Open the your-app-name-Info.plist file under "ionic-project-root/platforms/ios/your-app-name/" and add these lines:

```
<key>GADIsAdManagerApp</key>
<true/>
<key>GADApplicationIdentifier</key>
<string>ca-app-pub-XXXXXXX~YYYYYYY</string>
```

Being ca-app-pub-XXXXXXX~YYYYYYY your ios app ID in admob. Now the error should go away.

Answer (score 14):

[image]

There is a new procedure, you need to add GADIsAdManagerApp key for info.plist file with boolean YES value

Comment: This one is valid not just for Ionic. Thanks

Comment: Had the same problem with game made with Unity (Appodeal plugin), and your reply helped me! Thank you, saved my day

Answer (score 8):

For **Ionic App** with Admob plugin (I've tried just in Ioniv V3) you can add this in *./config.xml* under platform ios to auto populate app-name-info.plist file at every build time.

```
<platform name="ios">
   <config-file parent="GADApplicationIdentifier" target="*-Info.plist">
      <string>ca-app-pub-12345/12345</string>
   </config-file>

   <config-file parent="GADIsAdManagerApp" target="*-Info.plist">
      <true />
   </config-file>

   ... (other lines) ...

</platform>
```

Run `cordova prepare` to regenerated the file (additionally delete ios platform and reinstall it using: `ionic cordova platform rm ios` , `ionic cordova platform add ios`).

Comment: Problem with this is, if you already have your platform, sometimes rebuilding it can be a hassle, specially when you have a lot of plugins. It can take a lot of time and might need to reconfigure some stuff. I mean, this definitely should be included in the config.xml just in case for the future, but I would also take the shortcut of modifying the plist file and just leave the platform as it is.